# Need help to rewrite url using mod rewrite to omit one occurence

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following url

```
http://www.localhost/me/me/username
```

I would like to rewrite it to

```
http://www.localhost/me/username
```

Can any mod rewrite expert give me some advices? Below is my current mod rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(me/){2,}username$ /$1username [R=301,L]
```

It does this:

```
http://www.localhost/me/me/username => http://www.localhost/me/username
http://www.localhost/me/me/me/me/username => http://www.localhost/me/username
```

Or you seem want this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(me/){2,}username$ /$1username [R=301,L]
```

The latter will do this:

```
http://localhost/me/username => http://www.localhost/me/username
http://localhost/me/me/username => http://www.localhost/me/username
http://www.localhost/me/me/me/me/username => http://www.localhost/me/username
```